# Custom permalink structure: /%custom-post-type%/%custom-taxonomy%/%post-name%/

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to create a custom permalink structure that will allow me to accomplish the following.

1. I have a custom post type called "projects"
2. I have a custom taxonomy called "project-category" that is assigned to the CPT "projects"

I want my permalink structure to look like this:

projects/category/project-name

or

/%custom-post-type%/%custom-taxonomy%/%post-name%/

I've been able to succesfully use /%category%/ in permalinks for normal, out-of-the-box WP posts, but not for CPTs.

How would creating such a permalink structure affect the URLs or other pages? Is it possible de define a custom permalink structure and restrict it to a single CPT?

Thanks

Comment: Would this plugin solve your issue? https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: I'm always hesitant to use too many plugins, but I'll definetely give it a try! Thank you.

Comment: I totally agree with you, although lately I've been a bit more lenient with really basic plugins that are essentially just taking some grunt work away from us. Hope that works out for you!

Comment: Like Advanced Custom Fields - the greatest WP plugin of all time as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Indeed, ACF is an absolute must for any WordPress install! CPTP works wonderfuly, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Lucky for you, I *just* had to do this for a client project. I used [this answer on the WordPress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39862/13937) as a guide:

```
/**
 * Tell WordPress how to interpret our project URL structure
 *
 * @param array $rules Existing rewrite rules
 * @return array
 */
function so23698827_add_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
  $new = array();
  $new['projects/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?cpt_project=$matches[2]';
  $new['projects/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?cpt_project_category=$matches[1]';

  return array_merge( $new, $rules ); // Ensure our rules come first
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'so23698827_add_rewrite_rules' );

/**
 * Handle the '%project_category%' URL placeholder
 *
 * @param str $link The link to the post
 * @param WP_Post object $post The post object
 * @return str
 */
function so23698827_filter_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {
  if ( $post->post_type == 'cpt_project' ) {
    if ( $cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'cpt_project_category' ) ) {
      $link = str_replace( '%project_category%', current( $cats )->slug, $link );
    }
  }
  return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'so23698827_filter_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

When registering the custom post type and taxonomy, be sure to use the following settings:

```
// Used for registering cpt_project custom post type
$post_type_args = array(
  'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'projects/%project_category%',
    'with_front' => true
  )
);

// Some of the args being passed to register_taxonomy() for 'cpt_project_category'
$taxonomy_args = array(
  'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'projects',
    'with_front' => true
  )
);
```

Of course, be sure to flush rewrite rules when you're done. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was is a of a hurry so I had to rely on a plugin (which I prefer not to do) to do it quick. I'll implement this in future projects!

Comment: Have you ever tried to get this to work with sub-categories or know how I might get this to work with sub-categories?

Comment: This works; however, `get_post_type_archive_link('projects')` returns with the `%project_catgory%` in the url since the slug is defined with it.

Comment: This doesn't work with pages. :/ projects/category/project-name/page/2/ results in 404.

Comment: UPDATE: Fix for the pagination can be found here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40591/13291

Comment: I've followed this and am using subcategories, flushed the rewrite rules and still get a 404. Is there an htaccess edit that needs to happen as well?

Comment: @TabethaMoe In my short experience, url rewriting is entirely managed by Wordpress, therefore you should never have to edit your htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress changed a lot in the recent years there is a new solution for this.

```
// Used for registering cpt_project custom post type
$post_type_args = array(
  'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => '/%custom-post-type%/%custom-taxonomy%/%postname%/',
    'with_front' => true,
    'walk_dirs' => false,
  )
);
```

`%custom-post-type%` must match the name for your custom post type
`%custom-taxonomy%` must match the name for your taxonomy
that WordPress automatically creates the right rewrite rules and links
with `'walk_dirs' => false` you prevent WP from creating crazy rules like with only `[^/]+/` cause your link starts with a custom-post-type and often this dir walk isn't even needed cause u access only the sites in your structure or separate taxonomy sites.

With this your rewrite rules are as precise as possible, and you don't need to fetch the rules with

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'so23698827_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

and prepend them later on with

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'so23698827_filter_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

as mentioned in the accepted answer. This saves memory and execution time!

Hope this helps anyone, who is searching for this Problem with WP Versions > 5.X

Comment: Can you put a reference where you found this? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: found that by testing on my own server. It just worked. No documentation found for that.

Comment: @Alletkla thanks for this. It's sad that this very basic and expected requirement for CPT / Custom Taxonomies is not clearly explained in the docs, let alone being implemented simply in Permalinks out of the box. This does NOT work for me. Any ideas on how to register the custom taxonomy along with this CPT?