# wordpress custom post type category slug in url

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have custom post type (portfolio) with two different categories, then I have 2 pages showing posts from each of both categories.

The url when I call the page is something like mysite.com/pagename where pagename has the same name of the portfolio category.

My problem is when I go in the single portfolio the url changes into mysite.com/portfolio/portfolio-name

Is there any way to show the portfolio category in the url instead?
It should be like mysite.com/portfolio-category/portfolio-name

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone landing here, this question covers the same topic, and includes an answer which works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any of those are possible and configurable under Settings > Permalinks. Have a look at the Permalinks page for other possibilities.

One thing to note though, it's suggested to add a number at the beginning of your permalinks to reduce the number of rewrite rules WordPress has to generate to resolve all of your URLs.

Comment: in the permalinks i've chosen "sample-post/" which is a good option for all the other pages in the site, if i change that i would maybe (not so sure) solve there and i would have the problem elsewhere.

Comment: i need a rule that overwrite the default post type only when it comes to the custom post type and replace it with the relative category

Comment: have you referred this URL https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: changing the permalink settings i can achieve at most to this:

Comment: mysite.com/portfolio/category/post-name, i would like to remove the "portfolio" but as u can see it's not allowed:
https://s22.postimg.org/obz2h5bun/Schermata_2016_10_19_alle_14_29_18.png

Answer (score -1):

Register Your Taxonomy as Below.

Here "portfolio" is your "**Custom Post Type**" And
"portfolio-category" is your "**portfolio category**".

After adding this hook URL will display with "portfolio-category".As You want.

Try This will help you.

```
/* add action hook in function.php */
add_action( 'init', 'custom_function_toadd_taxonomyurl',0);
function custom_function_toadd_taxonomyurl() {

register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-category', array( 'portfolio' ), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Portfolio Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Category',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => 'portfolio-category',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-category')
    ));

}
```