# Understanding WP Permalinks, Custom Post Types and WP Query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type, permalinks, taxonomy

I'm having a nightmare with custom post types and getting a permalink structure that actually works. There are numerous posts on this site and the Wordpress StackExchange site that mention this sort of issue but none seem to work properly and I wonder if it may have to do with the age of those questions? FULL DISCLOSURE: I have already tried the plugins URL plugins suggested (yes, all of them!)

An example of an answered question, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name) (based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862) original question / answer) carefully and everything works in terms of showing the "archive" pages and going as deep in the URL structure as the original question requests however, I can never get the "single" page to show and always get 404 errors.

I've been facing this issue for weeks now and am slowly losing my mind. I don't want to do a shortcut and would rather be guided in the right direction or shown where I'm going wrong.

My final attempt is to "grab" the query and adjust the page accordingly, thing is, I don't quite understand how it works. So figuring out what is being queried when the URL is a querystring is simple enough. How do you do it when the URL is "custom_post_type_slug/taxonomy_slug/sub_taxonomy_slug/custom_post"

I'm open to just about any suggestion here, if you feel this question has been asked, you're right, it has been. Most of the answers are years old and repeated requests for support on the answers go ignored or the question remains unanswered.