# How to append a custom taxonomy to an existing page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The situation:

- I have a custom post type in Wordpress called **project**
- I have an archive page in Wordpress **/projects/**
- I have a custom post type (CPT) taxonomy attached to the **project** post type called **spaces**
- The taxonomy is non-hierachical, and contains items: **cars**, **vans**
- I have posts of type project called:
  **website.com/projects/electic-car-1/
  website.com/projects/combustion-van-1/**

What I've tried:

- Ideally, I'd enable "rewrite" and set "custom rewrite slug" to to **projects** (instead of spaces), and then remove "rewrite with front" to get rid of the spaces, however this breaks the existing links to the posts themselves (website.com/projects/electic-car-1/)

What I'd like:

- I would like to be able to use the link
  website.com/projects/ for the archive page (this works properly by default)
- I would like to be able to use the taxonomy filters to create a link structure like this:
  website.com/projects/cars/
  website.com/projects/vans/

What I suspect:

- I think this is a potentially a problem with permalinks?
- I also think this might just be something I'm fundamentally missing with how a post can be addressed in wordpress by a URL structure - namely, it would be possible to get to:

website.com/projects/electic-car-1/
website.com/projects/cars/electic-car-1/

which are the same post, and that may not be desirable for good reason? (as it is, I'm confused as to the impact for search - the idea here was to try and create a slightly more meaningful setup for search, but it may be it's making it worse?)

Thanks for reading, sorry if I've missed something really obvious, but having read a lot of help texts / SO question / watched a tonne of youtube / I can't seem to find anything on this specific question. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Just to update, per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name?rq=2 I've now tried the CPT Permalinks plug-in, which gets me almost there, but I'm still stuck with the name of the taxonomy in the url path, which I need to remove.